# Сравнение массива 1 и 2, при успехе копировать элементы массива 1 в 3-й - JS, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сравнить два имеющихся массива, если все элементы двух сравниваемых массивов будут равны (true), скопировать элементы массива 1 в массив 3.
Помимо этого должна быть погрешность. К примеру, сравнивая первые элементы массивов, 12 = 11 это false, но если при конкуляции 12 отнять 11, мы получим 1 (или -1 при другом сравнении чисел), то false сменить на true.
Подскажите каким способом я бы мог это сделать. В JS или в jQuery.

```
const array1 = [
    12, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5,
]

const wishArray2 = [
    11, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4,
] // массив с которым сравниваем массив 1.

let rezultArray3 = [
] // скопировать в этот массив.
```

Comment: идем по массиву (прдполагаем что длины равны). проверяем `abs(a[i] - b[i]) <= 1`, и смотрим, все ли элементы удовлетворяют этому условию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте `every` для проверки модуля разности элементов

```js
const a = [12, 7, 7, 7, 6, 5];
const b = [11, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4];

let result = a.every((v,idx) => Math.abs(v - b[idx]) <= 1) ? a : null;

console.log(result);
```